# Finding max common substrings in 2 strings using Hash and Binary search

Tags: hash, hashtable, binary-search, longest-substring

Suppose I have 2 big strings of size 10^5, How can I search for max common sub strings from both strings with complexity O(NlogN) using Hash and Binary Search.
Explanation with code will be of great help :)

Comment: Sounds a lot like homework you haven't bothered to attempt....

Comment: You can say it was kind of homework, and I was able to achieve in O(N^2logN), But was looking for a solution with O(NlogN). 
The problem was I was while matching the hashes for strings I was also running a loop for checking char to char leading to n^2 for more accurate result. If you have any solution where I can achieve this in nlogn very accurately, please share. (You can share it as a story also instead of code ;) )

Comment: You'll find some "stories" about implementation on [wikipedia]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), with efficiencies too.  A quick google turns up [implementations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-substring/).  Hope that helps.